# cython static shaped array views

Tags: multidimensional-array, cython

In cython, one can use array views, e.g.

```
cdef void func(float[:, :] arr)
```

In my usage the second dimension should always have a shape of 2. Can I tell cython this? I was thinking of something like:

```
cdef void func(float[:, 2] arr)
```

but this results in an invalid syntax; Or is it possible to have something more similar to c++, e.g.

```
cdef void func(tuple<float, float>[:] arr)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 2D static array instead. Just use the pointer notation. Here is how you achieve it

```
def pyfunc():
    # static 1D array
    cdef float *arr1d = [1,-1, 0, 2,-1, -1, 4]
    # static 2D array
    cdef float[2] *arr2d = [[1,.2.],[3.,4.]]
    # pass to a "cdef"ed function
    cfunc(arr2d)

# your function signature would now look like this
cdef void cfunc(float[2] *arr2d):
    print("my 2D static array")
    print(arr2d[0][0],arr2d[0][1],arr2d[1][0],arr2d[1][1])
```

Calling it you get:

```
>>> pyfunc()
my 2D static array
1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0
```

Comment: Follow up question: How can I convert the data of a numpy array to `float[2] *` ?

Comment: @user1447257 What do you want to achieve with that. It sounded like you wanted a static shaped array for performance purposes. But if this is just a syntactic sugar in your code, you might as well use the generic memory view syntax `float [:,:]`. As `numpy` arrays are dynamic they won't bind to `float[2] *` unless you want to explicitly copy the data.

Comment: For less cache-misses, I would do the copying to a contiguous array anyways, since my code iterates over the entries multiple times. I was thinking, that maybe a cast to a `float[2] *` data-type will increase the performance a bit, because the pointer could be incremented completely linearly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is really supported, but if you want to do this then the best way is probably to use memoryviews of `structs` (which are compatible with numpys custom dtypes):

```
import numpy as np

cdef packed struct Pair1: # packed ensures it matches custom numpy dtypes 
                # (but probably doesn't matter here!)
    double x
    double y

# pair 1 matches arrays of this dtype    
pair_1_dtype = [('x',np.float64), ('y',np.float64)]

cdef packed struct Pair2:
    double data[2]

pair_2_dtype = [('data',np.float64, (2,))]

def pair_func1(Pair1[::1] x):
    # do some very basic work
    cdef Pair1 p
    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    p.x = 0; p.y = 0
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        p.x += x[i].x
        p.y += x[i].y

    return p # take advantage of auto-conversion to a dict

def pair_func2(Pair2[::1] x):
    # do some very basic work
    cdef Pair2 p
    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    p.data[0] = 0; p.data[1] = 0
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        p.data[0] += x[i].data[0]
        p.data[1] += x[i].data[1]

    return p # take advantage of auto-conversion to a dict
```

and a function to show you how to call it:

```
def call_pair_funcs_example():
    # generate data of correct dtype
    d = np.random.rand(100,2)
    d1 = d.view(dtype=pair_1_dtype).reshape(-1)
    print(pair_func1(d1))

    d2 = d.view(dtype=pair_2_dtype).reshape(-1)
    print(pair_func2(d2))
```

---

The thing I'd like to have done is:

```
ctypedef double[2] Pair3

def pair_func3(Pair3[::1] x):
    # do some very basic work
    cdef Pair3 p
    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    p[0] = 0; p[1] = 0
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        p[0] += x[i][0]
        p[1] += x[i][1]

    return p # ???
```

That compiles successfully, but I couldn't find any way of converting it from numpy. If you could work out how to get this version to work then I think it would be the most elegant solution.

---

Note that I'm not convinced of the performance advantages of any of these solutions. Your best move is probably to tell Cython that the trailing dimension is contiguous in memory (e.g. `double [:,::1]`) but let it be any size.